# Selecionar que atributos o GET retorna da lista em Rest

Tags: restful

Sres(as), tenho a seguinte dúvida. Tenho uma aplicação em Rest que quando peço pra me retornar a lista, vem com muitos campos desnecessários, "exemplo abaixo". Como faço para selecionar os atributos da classe entity que ele deve retornar?

Meu get:

```
@GetMapping
public List<Nota> listNotas(){
return notaRepository.findAll();
}
```

Quando dou um get tenho o seguinte retorno.

```
{
    "id": 28,
    "nota": 10,
    "dataNota": [
        2017,
        10,
        10
    ],
    "professor": {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": null,
        "matricula": null,
        "observacao": null,
        "dataNascimento": null,
        "ativo": null
    },
    "materia": {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": null
    },
    "aluno": {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": null,
        "matricula": null,
        "observacao": null,
        "dataNascimento": null,
        "ativo": null,
        "nomeResponsavel": null,
        "foneResponsavel": null
    }
}
```

Gostaria que retornasse com menos campos como por ex.

```
{
    "id": 28,
    "nota": 10,
    "dataNota": [
        2017,
        10,
        10
    ],
    "professor": {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": null,
               },
    "materia": {
           "id": 1,
           "nome": null
    },
    "aluno": {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": null,
        "matricula": null,
        }
}
```

Comment: Nesse caso, creio que a melhor maneira seria criar uma query especifica para retornar os resultados que você quer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De uma olhada em http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation

Basicamente:

**1 - Crie uma classe:**

```
public class Views{
 public static class Public{}
 public static class General extends public{}
}
```

O que estiver em public, so aparecera quando public e general o que estiver empublic e general.

**2 - nas entidades anote os atributos com:**

***ps:faça isso nos relacionamentos tbm***

```
@JsonView(Views.Public.class) ou @JsonView(Views.General.class)
```

**3 - E por fim no getmapping**

```
@GetMapping
@JsonView(Views.Public.class)
public List<Nota> listNotas(){
  return notaRepository.findAll();
}
```